# Unable to add custom settings file to Asp.Net Core 3.1 WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, configuration

I am writing a WebApi for tracking my puppy's doings (potty breaks, crate training etc). The api has a front-end component written in Blazor, but that is not part of this question.

On my github projects, I never use the file **appsettings.json** in fear of accidentally commiting it and thus exposing any secrets. Instead, I wanted to add my own appsettings file as such:

```cs
        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration(config => {
                    var basePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
                    var fileName = "puppytrackersettings.json";
                    var fullPath = Path.Combine(basePath, fileName);

                    if(File.Exists(fullPath))
                    {
                        config.SetBasePath(basePath);
                        config.AddJsonFile(fileName, optional: true);
                    }
                })
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
```

This way, the settings file can be maintained in the "My Documents" folder ("/" on linux), safely tucked away far from the source code.

**PROBLEM**
The problem is that the config is only updated with this added json file while in the *CreateHostBuilder()* method. Once the configuration gets activated in *Startup.cs* the configuration is back to it's default config. I see that the configurationproviders are 5 before entering *CreateHostBuilder()*, then it jumps up to 6 once I add my json file, but then when *Startup.ConfigureServices()* runs, the configuration is back to 5 again.

I've tried numerous ways of creating a configuration for the webapi, but none work.

**WORKAROUND**
So far, my workaround is to use application secrets in VS, but since some of the settings, such as Application Insights Telemetry Key are shared, it is a pain to replicate across all the microservices, since I can't point to an existing app secret.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong, or how to do this correctly?

Version of .Net Core is 3.1.101
Visual Studio: 16.4.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is I correctly understand that you want to store some configs (like passwords or API-keys) in separate folder? So, it's very reasonable to not  store such data in the git-repository.

**FIRST SOLUTION**

Do you know  about `AddInMemoryCollection` or `AddEFConfiguration` or `AddCommandLine` or `AddEnvironmentVariables`?

By this methods you can extend your settings file by values from Database, Commandline Parameters or Environment variables.

If I were you I will use `AddEnvironmentVariables`.

See more information here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1

**ONE MORE SOLUTION**

You can add file with specific data to you code and ignore it in GIT. So, if this file will be optional then your application will not fail but you will have posibility to changle configuration.

To do this make something like this:

```
public IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }
public IHostingEnvironment Environment { get; set; }

public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IHostingEnvironment environment)
{
   Environment = environment;
   Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.secrets.json")
            .Build();
}
```

and add appsettings.secrets.json to you git ignore

**ONE MORE SOLUTION**

So, why you use `SetBasePath`?
Why you not use  `AddJsonFile`  with full path? Like this:

```
if(File.Exists(fullPath))
{
    config.AddJsonFile(fileName, optional: true);
}
```

Comment: This works, but it is not as simple as sending a settings file to a co-developer and stating "Put this in your documents folder". I have also used the "Secrets file" as an alternative, and configured each project with the same Secrets ID so they all point to the same location. 

My question was just based on simplicity of sharing. It's easier to tell a developer to drop something into "my documents" than to tell him to locate the secrets location of the project and storing a file there, but that's a fair workaround. I only use environment variables in production.

Comment: So, why are you do not want to use Second solution?  You can add your file to .gitignore file and commit it. Then if anyone will add this file to git folder it will not commit.

Comment: I add one more option for you.

Comment: I tried, it doesen't seem to work at all. That's the original problem, it starts out with 5 configurationelements, then I call config.AddJsonFile() it increases to 6, but once it's back in Startup.ConfigureServices() that Json file is gone again from Configuration. Looks like there's something inside ConfigureHostBuilder that ignores/resets configuration.

Comment: Are you try to use c:/ as base path? May be your path contains not only English symbols?

Comment: No weird symbols, no spaces: "C:\Users\pedro\OneDrive\Documents"

Comment: Are you try to run it as Administrator? It can failed with access denied error.

Comment: Ok, THAT solved it! I wasn't running VS as administrator! The log says nothing about lacking the rights to read MyDocuments folder. That is awesome!!

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a custom settings file to your project. Eg customAppsettings.json

add a setting like this

```
{
"yoursettingname": "yoursettingvalue"
}
```

2. Add the below code to your startup.cs constructor

   ```
     public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
     public Startup()
        {
            Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .AddJsonFile($"customAppsettings.json")
            .Build();
        }
   ```
3. Anywhere in your startup.cs access it like this

   Configuration["yoursettingname"]